# Stored ProcedureIn ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
**stored procedure**
```

**How to call this procedure in mvc**
**Please Explain **

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[RegistrationInsert](  
@empEmail nvarchar(max),  
@password nvarchar (max)  
)  
as begin  
insert into [Registration ] ([EmployeeName],[EmployeeEmail],[Password],[PhoneNumber],[Role],[EmployeeID])  
select [EmployeeName],[EmployeeMailID],@password,[EmployeePhoneNumber],[EmployeeDesignation],[EmployeeID]  
from [Employeedata ]  
where [EmployeeMailID] = @empEmail  
end  
GO
```

Comment: All you need, you can learn here for free: https://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1):

If we want to work with the Stored Procedure then need to use the Code First Migrations that is very safe, smooth and productive. So use the following procedure.

**Step 1**

***Enable-Migrations***

**Step 2**

Now the data context class will use the Stored Procedure. Open the Context class and update the code as shown below:

Open the Tools-> NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console and enter the following command:

```
namespace MvcStoredProcedureSample.Models  
{  
    public class MovieDbContext : DbContext  
    {  
        public MovieDbContext() : base( "name = MovieDbContext" )  
        {  
        }  

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }  

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
        {  
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().MapToStoredProcedures();  
        }  

    }  
}
```

**Step 3**

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;  

    public partial class MyMovieSP : DbMigration  
    {  
        public override void Up()  
        {  
            CreateStoredProcedure(  
                "dbo.Movie_Insert",  
                p => new  
                    {  
                        Name = p.String(),  
                        ReleaseDate = p.DateTime(),  
                        Category = p.String(),  
                    },  
                body:  
                    @"INSERT [dbo].[Movies]([Name], [ReleaseDate], [Category])  
                      VALUES (@Name, @ReleaseDate, @Category)  

                      DECLARE @ID int  
                      SELECT @ID = [ID]  
                      FROM [dbo].[Movies]  
                      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()  

                      SELECT t0.[ID]  
                      FROM [dbo].[Movies] AS t0  
                      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[ID] = @ID"  
            );
        }
public override void Down()  
        {   
            DropStoredProcedure("dbo.Movie_Insert");  
        } 
}
```

Build the solution. Now in the Package Manager Console enter the following command:

Add-Migration MyMovieSP

You can use any name in the place of MyMovieSP.

**Step 4**

We need to tell the database to create the MyMovieSP. So just enter the following command in the Package Manager Console,

***Update-Database***

For better understanding visit complete article **[using Stored Procedure In ASP.NET MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-6-in-mvc-5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a viewmodel (Register)

```
public class Register 
{
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "User", ErrorMessage = "Email Already 
     Exists")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
    public string EmployeeEmail {get;set;}

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is 
    Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 6 Characters")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2: Add a ADO.Net EntityModel from database.

Add a tables and stored-procedures

[image: Adding tables and stored procedures from database]

[image: Open Modal browser and see sp(RegistrationInsert)]

Step 3: Create object for database like

```
Database db = new Database();

public ActionResult Register(Register view)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    string message = "";
    db.RegistrationInsert(empEmail: view.EmployeeEmail, password: 
    view.Password);
    ViewBag.Message = "Registered Successfully";
    return View();
}
```

Step 4: Create a Razorview:

[image: Razorview]

Comment: This has nothing to do with stored procedures and is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Its a perfect answer . its working fine to me please check it once .just try it .

Comment: This answer does not answer your question. Yes, the code might work on your machine, but that does not mean that other people reading this answer can do anything with it. Explain how you got the method `db.RegistrationInsert()` to work.

Comment: Please Check it once